# Validate input to be a valid fraction

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

Need to validate input from a input box to be positive fraction in one of the three formats:

1. Integer - 1, 2 15, 15, ... etc.
2. Fraction - 1/2, 3/4, 5/16, ...etc.
3. Both Integer and fraction - 1 1/2, 3 5/15, 12 5/5, ...
   etc.

But reject 2 2 1/2, 2 a/2, or a 15/32 etc.

I cannot even come up with a close one. I was thinking this but not even close. `/\d{0,2}(\s\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2})?`

Comment: Was 2 15 supposed to be like that on 1?

Answer (score 0):

This checks for two integers separated by a `/` character, preceded by an optional integer-with-space. It also includes a separate check that will match on a lone integer.

```
^(?:\d+ )?\d+\/\d+$|^\d+$
```

Comment: Why would create a non capture group - and not allow for a space?

Comment: The group is to allow for a space, but only if there is an integer ahead of the fraction.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) using the `|` to match either a digit, a fraction, 2 digits or a digit and fraction.

If you want to match 1 or 2 digits you could use `\d{1,2}` instead of `\d+`

```
^\d+(?:\/\d+$|(?: \d+(?:\/\d+)?)?)$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\/\d+$` Match only a fraction (`/` and 1+ digits and assert end of string)
  - `|` Or
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `\d+(?:/\d+)?` Match a space, 1+ digits and optional `/` and 1+ digits
  - `)?` Close non capture group and make it optional
- `)` Close non capture group
- `$`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/V48E9Y/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
^(\d+\s+\d+\/\d+|\d+\/\d+|\d+)$
```

- One capture group: ()
- ^ to begin
- $ to end
- \s for space (1+) when dealing with c below..
- | for 3 combos:

  - a) int + fraction
  - b) fraction
  - c) int

You are still going to have to deal with top heavy fractions with extra code interrogating capture groups.

To expand on this.. the following tweak will facilitate that.

```
^(\d+\s+(\d+)\/(\d+)|(\d+)\/(\d+)|\d+)$
```

Then, you will have to either look at either:

- capture group 4 & 5 if dealing with just fraction (b), or
- capture group 2 & 3 if dealing with integer plus fraction (a)

So to clarify, for 5 3/4:
Capture groups are:

1 = 5 3/4

2 = 3

3 = 4

For 2/3:
Capture groups are:

1 = 2/3

4 = 2

5 = 3

And if you want to interrogate the integers too..

```
^(\(d+)\s+(\d+)\/(\d+)|(\d+)\/(\d+)|\d+)$
```

That will shunt capture group 2->3, 3-> 4, 4->5, 5->6 above.. and the capture group 2 will now give you the integer as well for scenario a).
Capture group 1 will be the integer for scenario c).

You can see it in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/poCGL1/3).